# Cycling approach in navigation controller, user prospect

Tags: objective-c

In my application I have 2 view controllers, ViewController1 and ViewController2. According to requirement I have to push ViewController2 on ViewController1. And in ViewController2 there is a link which will again push ViewController1, so this process of pushing will go on. Now my question is this good practise of pushing view controller like this according to user's accessibility?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not a good practice, for sure. You can simply pop when you want to call VC1 from VC2.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to keep on pushing views on top of each other because if the user feels to go back he will have to keep going back for the no.of times the user has pushed the views.

You could try either of the two :

- push view2 on view1, and pop view2 from view1
  or
- If your logic permits, add subview view2 on view1, and remove from superview view2. But I would say 1st step is better.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice as it may damage the view controller hierarchy. 
If it's a strong prospect, then either:

- just let the navigation controller pop vc2, show vc1 / vc1 pop modal view controller vc2

or

- Instead of navigation controller, using your own customized UIViewController containment, so that the pop from vc2 may animate in the way as if vc1 is pushed in.